# Geeting exception finding no. of sheets in xlsx files using Apache poi

Tags: java, exception, apache-poi

```
int sheets = 0;
    try {
        Workbook book = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
        sheets = book.getNumberOfSheets();
        book.close(); //Exception occurs in this line
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.warn(e.getMessage());
        throw new Exception("exception in readding number of sheets", e.getCause());
    }
    return sheets;
```

I get this exception:

```
org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JRuntimeException: Fail to save: an error occurs while saving the package : part.
```

Is there any workaround to this exception?

Comment: You must save the Workbook to something, before close the workbook.Take a look at this link http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#NewWorkbook

Comment: That's the thing I just want the number of sheets. And nothing else. It works fine for xls files but I get this error in case of xlsx files.

Comment: try use readonly mode. Files.newInputStream(path, StandardOpenOption.READ)

Comment: Same Error org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JRuntimeException: Fail to save: an error occurs while saving the package : part.

Comment: See this example - http://obscuredclarity.blogspot.in/2011/12/get-sheet-names-from-excel-file-using.html

Comment: HSSFWorkbook is used for xls file. I am having problem with xlsx files.

Comment: Which version of poi library do you use?

Comment: version 3.11 is the one I am using

Comment: Do my answer solve your problem?

Comment: Nope! When I close book for Workbook book = new XSSFWorkbook(file2);
I get an error. Though HSSF works with xls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the result I test on poi 3.11 version as you say in comment.

Your code is work fine on me!

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class POITest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        File file = new File("F:\\test.xlsx");

        int sheets = 0;
        try {
            Workbook book = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
            sheets = book.getNumberOfSheets();
            System.out.println(sheets);
            book.close(); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            InputStream file2 = new FileInputStream("F:\\test.xlsx");
            Workbook book = new XSSFWorkbook(file2);
            sheets = book.getNumberOfSheets();
            System.out.println(sheets);
            book.close(); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

For the code above it can run and print out the number of sheet without exception. I also provide another way to new a `Workbook`. If you still meet the exception, maybe you can try another 'pure' excel file ( new a excel file and save it directly without insert any data) and test it again.